# Shows heroku address instead of my domain address

Tags: heroku, namecheap

I deployed my app to heroku and set it up in namecheap.com

I added custom doamin like this

[image]

Adn in namecheap

[image]

and when I typed texty.marketing in address bar in browser.
it shows me heroku app address like this

**https://whispering-hamlet-32114.herokuapp.com/**

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku domains:add example.com

heroku domains:add www.example.com

heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

Here is a youtube video to make it easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=29s

Please let me know if this does work